# .htaccess 301 redirect from //example.org/subdir to //subdir/example.org as is

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This hasn't be as simple as I thought it would be.

I'm trying to do a .htaccess 301 redirect from //example.org/subdir to //subdir/example.org as is. What I mean by as is, is that all the redirects I've tried so far do //example.org/subdir -> //subdir.example.org/subdir. Which is really annoying!

I may just end up using an alternative way that is easier to do, but .htaccess just seemed the best way.

Comment: `Redirect permanent /subdir http://subdir/example.org`, place in in server config or .htaccess of the server `example.org`

Comment: Are you averse to praise? Why not answer? :| Thank you!

Comment: Because may be I did not understand correctly or the question is not complete and requires additional details and some chatting will be needed. Just in case if result is not the one that was expected and so on. I'm here not for the points )

Comment: @defaye: Has your problem been solved? If not post your current .htaccess in question.

Comment: It has been solved by @Cheery many thanks~ I had never tried the permanent redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect permanent /subdir http://subdir/example.org`, place in in server config or `.htaccess` of the server `example.org`